# Как разделить подключение стилей для разных файлов header.php?

Tags: wordpress

В мультиязычном сайте на wordpress для русского языка подключаются одни стили и скрипты, для английского и китайского - другие. Я создал два файла: header.php для русского и header-foreign.php для других языков. Подключаю их соответственно get_header() и get_header('foreign'). Встал вопрос, как в functions.php мне сделать проверку типа

```
if(header name == 'foreign')
```

, чтобы на разные файлы подключать разные стили и скрипты.

Comment: Использую плагин polylang, сделал проверку по языку и на нужный язык подключаю нужные стили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно теги script формирует функция wp_head, вызванная в секции head документа. Предварительно нужно добавить эти скрипты в очередь вызовом wp_enqueue_script. Вот здесь вам и надо разделять и властвовать.

functions.php:

```
$scripts = [
    'ru' => [
        [
            'handle' => 'scripts1',
            'src' => '/assets/scripts/script1.js'
        ],
        [
            'handle' => 'scripts2',
            'src' => '/assets/scripts/script2.js'
        ]
    ],
    'en' => [
        [
            'handle' => 'scripts3',
            'src' => '/assets/scripts/script3.js'
        ],
        [
            'handle' => 'scripts4',
            'src' => '/assets/scripts/script4.js'
        ]
    ]
];

$language = get_language ();

foreach ($scripts [$language] as $script)
    wp_enqueue_script ($script ['handle'], $script ['src']);
```

Код функции get_language я вам привести не могу, ибо из вопроса не очевидно как именно отличить одну версию сайта от другой.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте магическую константу `__FILE__`:

```
if ( false !== strpos( __FILE__, 'header-foreign.php' ) ) {
    // подключение
}
```